# Adding own 'accents' during runtime with Mahapps.Metro

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I've been using Mahapps.Metro for a while now, and I love the accentcolors. But I just now thought of an idea where the user can select own colors and add them to the `MahApps.Metro.ThemeManager.DefaultAccents` -List and then use it. But; how would I go about doing this? I know that the ThemeManager has a function called `ChangeTheme` which takes an application (the target application), an `Accent` and a `Theme` (which is Dark or Light)

The Accent object is made up of a Name, and a ResourceDictionary which looks like [this](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml)

So I thought that I could create a own ResourceDictionary like the one I linked and allow the user to change colors, and name them.
But how would I create a resourcedictionary during runtime?

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this in vb.net (with two checkboxes for Theme):

```
    Dim accent As MahApps.Metro.Accent = New MahApps.Metro.Accent("Green", New Uri("pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Green.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
    Dim LightTheme As MahApps.Metro.AppTheme = New MahApps.Metro.AppTheme("BaseLight", New Uri("pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
    Dim DarkTheme As MahApps.Metro.AppTheme = New MahApps.Metro.AppTheme("BaseDark", New Uri("pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseDark.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
    If Me.DarkThemeSelect_check.IsChecked = True Then
        ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current, accent, DarkTheme)
    ElseIf Me.LightThemeSelect_check.IsChecked = True Then
        ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current, accent, LightTheme)
    End If
```

If you only need to change theme (Dark or Light):

```
    ThemeManager.ChangeAppTheme(Application.Current, "BaseLight")
```